# Receiving user names varying success

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We've been building a teams bot using Microsoft Bot Framewok v4.x.

On every conversation update, we are getting users details such as name from the MS Team.

However, for some users we are not getting user's name from the MS teams. We tried but couldn't identify any specific pattern for this, but there were several cases where we are not getting user's name.

It seems pretty random.

Is there anything that we are missing?

Comment: To clarify, you mean individual messages don't include the `recipient.name` property, or it's null/empty string?

Comment: it's about an empty string..

Comment: Any thoughts @BillBliss-MSFT ?

Comment: Is there any differences between these users in the directory (Active Directory or AAD)?

Comment: Are they guest users? Until there's a more specific repo we can only guess.